# Converting String to date-JAVA

Tags: java

I am trying to convert string to date for my jdbc program.I have tried the following method

```
        DateFormat Formatter=null;
        Date convertedDate=null;
        Formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MMM-YYYY",Locale.ENGLISH);
        try {
            convertedDate=(Date)Formatter.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        java.sql.Date sqlDate=new java.sql.Date(convertedDate.getTime());
        System.out.println(date);
        System.out.println(convertedDate);
```

The problem I am facing is for example if I am passing '30-NOV-2001' as the parameter,when I convert this into Date using DateFormat and store it in convertedDate,I am getting "Sun Dec 31 00:00:00 IST 2000" as the output which is obviously wrong.So please help me out on this.

Comment: try with Formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);

Comment: [as allways for formatting, check what's the meaning of the format you are using...](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `"dd-MMM-yyyy"`,

```
 DateFormat Formatter=null;
        Date convertedDate=null;
        Formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MMM-YYYY",Locale.ENGLISH);
        try {
            convertedDate=(Date)Formatter.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        java.sql.Date sqlDate=new java.sql.Date(convertedDate.getTime());
        System.out.println(date);
        System.out.println(convertedDate);
```

D means day in year
d means day in month

Look **[Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)** for more info

Comment: @SaiSankalp I am glad

Comment: Yeah I have accepted the answer.Again thanks for your help :)